# Static CDC ACM device binding

Tags: linux, mount, usb, serial-port, automounting

I'm using a buildroot linux on IMX6 board. 
I have 2 CDC ACM device, a reader and a modem.

My modem have always been on /dev/ttyACM0 and I want it to stay that way.
The problem is that my reader is "stealing" ACM0.

I want to force my reader to take anything but ACM0.

One solution could be to wait for the modem to take ACM0 before starting the reader, is that even possible ?

Another would be to force the reader to take ACM1 for example.

I've tried udev rules, they are great to symlink but the original dev file is still here.

Is there any way using setserial ?

Comment: There is nothing to stop you renaming the device afterwards, though I dont know what happens when the device is unplugged. `sudo mv /dev/ttyACM0  /dev/ttyWasACM0`....